# Postgres - run query, if null, run a different query - all in 1 query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I merge these 2 queries into 1 query?  is it even possible? (Postgres 14)

```
select * from T
where T.guid = someguid
```

If the first query returns null, get the result of the second query:

```
select * from T
where T.default = 'true'
```

I read about 'exist' but it returns true/false and not the result itself, so couldn't figure out how to use it to solve my problem.

Comment: By `null`, do you mean if the first query returns no record?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I used the wrong terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
with t1 as (
  select * 
  from T
  where T.guid = someguid
)
select *
from t1
union all
select * 
from T
where T.default = 'true'
  and not exists (select * from t1);
```

The second part of the union will only be run, if the CTE didn't return anything. So it's either the first part or the second that returns something.

Answer (score 1):

as you mentioned, this can be done using `exists` as follows:

```
Select * From T
Where T.guid = someguid Or
      (Not Exists (Select * From T Where T.guid = someguid) And T.default = 'true')
```